# onchange variable returning value once, then undefined and then giving error

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to Javascript, have been learning but got stuck and thought to try a project to see if I could learn something out of it.
Now I am building a form with multiple selections, I got around to the form giving different values to a variable depending on the selection but it works only on the first time I make a selection, after that if I try changing it it returns undetermined, if I change selection again it gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at a.onchange"

this code shows the error on one variable selection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Perio Staging and Grading</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>Severity (Site of greater loss)</h2>
            <div><label for="CAL">Clinical attachment level:</label>
                <select name="CAL" id="CAL" >
                    <option value="">--Interdental CAL--</option>
                    <option value="low">1-2mm</option>
                    <option value="medium">3-4mm</option>
                    <option value="high">&#62;5mm</option>
                    <option value="naCal" >Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <button id="debug">Submit</button>
    <div id="result">

    </div>

    <script>
    
    let a = document.getElementById('CAL');
    a.onchange = (ev) =>{
      a= (a.value);} //Gets the CAL value of low,high,medium or naCal
    </script>
</body>
```

I Tried a few days to understand why but I really dont get it, logically I would want the arrow function to assign a new value to a based on the selection in CAL.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to assign the value of the dropdown option to the select element itself. Instead, assign it to a results variable. I'm also assigning it the event token's target value on change, but your way appears fine too. I think what is causing your code to only work once is that the select element is being overwritten on the first change event.

```js
const sel = document.getElementById('CAL');
let res
sel.onchange = (ev) => {
  res = ev.target.value;
  console.log(res)
}
```

```html
<h2>Severity (Site of greater loss)</h2>
<div><label for="CAL">Clinical attachment level:</label>
  <select name="CAL" id="CAL">
    <option value="">--Interdental CAL--</option>
    <option value="low">1-2mm</option>
    <option value="medium">3-4mm</option>
    <option value="high">&#62;5mm</option>
    <option value="naCal">Not available</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="debug">Submit</button>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, with this I did solve the problem completely! I really appreciate that you took your time to answer!